# Is my question topic valid for this site?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask a big-list type question along the lines of generating a list of underwater compound films. Some of the other .SE sites allow this type of question, on occasion (as long as it's not too broad), but I haven't seen that many for this site.

Is this an appropriate type of question for this site?

It would be a community wiki where people could add films of that specific category. It wouldn't get too big because there aren't that many.

(Hopefully this isn't a duplicate post, sorry if it is).

Comment: While I have to agree with *Andrew*'s answer, I'm very glad you brought this to meta. There are some kinds of list questions I feel might be on-topic (though, even that [isn't really decided yet](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1060/49)), but your kind of big-list-of-films is not, I think.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I definitely agree with this

Comment: Thanks for coming to meta - but I agree with what's been said so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to say no.

Generally we're not in favour of this type of question. Whilst I can understand the logic of isolated exceptions, allowing one could just open a floodgate - we could end up with lists of horror films, or the best rom-coms, or the best fantasy films, or the best post-Nazi Germany films, or the best Georgian era period dramas and so on and so forth...

As there's no end to potential list questions, I think it's much better to avoid them from the start.

Comment: Agreed, likewise I don't think slamming a Community Wiki sticker on them solves the problem.